# How to make a POST request and use the ID of the author?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this model `Game` and I have a working `GET` method and would like to create new `Game` objects in my database by using a POST request.

I have `Game` like this:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

I have a view like this:

```
class GameDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, game_slug):
        try:
            return Game.objects.filter(slug=game_slug)
        except Game.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, game_slug, format=None):
        game = self.get_object(game_slug).first()
        serializer = GameSerializer(game)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        game_data = request.data
        game_data['owner'] = { 'username': 'admin', 'email': 'admin@example.com'} // just to test

        serializer = GameSerializer(data=game_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If I send the server a POST request with the following body:

```
 {
    "name": "Posted game",
    ... // ommiting owner field
}
```

It looks like the server thinks I want to create a new user, but I just want the game to be associated with the userId

```
{
    "owner": {
        "username": [
            "user with this username already exists."
        ]
    }
}
```

If instead I set the `game_data['owner']` to the userID directly it complains that it's expecting a dictionary.

How can I make it so that when I `GET` a game I see the owner (username and email) and when I post it can just add the logged in user?

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            "name",
            "owner",
            ...
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the best solution is to create 2 serializers and use the right one for the right endpoint:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")

class ReadGameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            "name",
            "owner",
            ...
        )

class WriteGameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            "name",
            "owner",
            ...
        )
```

And then update your view:

```
class GameDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, game_slug):
        try:
            return Game.objects.filter(slug=game_slug)
        except Game.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, game_slug, format=None):
        game = self.get_object(game_slug).first()
        serializer = ReadGameSerializer(game)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        game_data = request.data
        game_data['owner'] = request.user # if the user is authenticated

        serializer = WriteGameSerializer(data=game_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Another solution would be to make the [nested serializer writable](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), but out of experience this solution is more difficult to maintain.

Comment: This worked! In my case I had to do `game_data['owner'] = request.user.id` because I had `__str__`'ed User to an email

Answer (score 0):

There area many ways to associate, If you want to associate the logged in user with Game, than pass request in serializer

```
...
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = GameSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": requeset})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Modify your serializer,
`serializers.CharField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())` this will automatically get your user from request and will associate with owner field in `Game` Model

Override the `to_representation` method to manipulate the response data

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.CharField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            "name",
            "owner",
            ...
        )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['owner'] = {"username":instance.owner.username, "email": instance.owner.email}
        return representation
```